# Differences in the outputs of ofNullable method of Optional class in Java 8

Tags: java, java-8

When I run the below code snippet as expected I get Optional.empty

```
   //Example 1
    Double dbNull = null;
    Optional nullableOptional = Optional.ofNullable( dbNull );
    System.out.println(nullableOptional);
```

But when I run the below code snippet,

```
    //Example 2
    Double doubleNull = null;
    Optional nullableOptional1 = Optional.ofNullable( 1/doubleNull );
    System.out.println(nullableOptional1);
```

I get.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.main.java8.streams.CreatingOptionalValuesDemo.main(CreatingOptionalValuesDemo.java:30)
```

I was expecting that it would return an Optional.empty for the second example too. Can anyone explain me why it behaves this way.

Comment: Has **nothing** to do with optionals: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html

Comment: Beyond that:you are using raw types by omitting the parameter. Never do that. Focus on the basics first. And pay more details on the exception messages. They would have told you where the problem really occurs.

Answer (score 0):

First, let's recap the usage of [**`ofNullable`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#ofNullable-T-).

> [**`ofNullable`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#ofNullable-T-) Returns an Optional describing the specified value, if
>   non-null, otherwise returns an empty Optional.

The **[`Optional<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html)** type is intended as a safer alternative for a reference of type `T` that either refers to an object or is null, and you're breaking this rule.

When you perform `1 / doubleNull` as the argument to the [**`ofNullable`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#ofNullable-T-) method,  you're essentially unboxing the `doubleNull` to a primitive `double` type which throws the exception and therefore the [**`ofNullable`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#ofNullable-T-) is not invoked at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you are expecting to get an `Optional.empty`, maybe what you want is to call `map` on your nullable:

```
Double dbNull = null;
Optional nullableOptional = Optional.ofNullable( dbNull );
Optional inverseOptional = nullableOptional.map(x -> 1/x);
```

Here `inverseOptional` will be `empty`. On the other hand, if `nullableOptional` was holding some value, then `inverseOptional` would be holding the inverse of it.

Using the combinator method `map` is the correct way to safely protect yourself against `NullPointerException`

Answer (score 0):

The statement `Optional#ofNullable` is never ran at all in your second case since `null.doubleValue()` throws a `NullPointerException`. when do some mathematic operations on a wrapper type `Double` the compiler will auto-unboxing the wrapper type to the primitive type `double`.

```
//      your code is same as below but it done by compiler ---v
Optional nullableOptional1 = Optional.ofNullable( 1/doubleNull.doubleValue());
```

You can using [Optional#map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) to achieve your way, for example:

```
Optional nullableOptional1 = Optional.ofNullable(doubleNull).map(it->1/it);
//                                                                 |
//                                                                 |
// Notes: if the value is absent, the provided mapping function is never called
```